# How do I type-hint a list of lambdas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, typing

How can I type-hint a list of functions or lambdas in python? Something like:

```
a: list[function] = [lambda x: x ** 2]
```

but working?

Comment: Create a list of lambdas, iterate through them, check what the value of it with `type()`, and try using that where you have "function"? Also try using `typing.List` instead of `list`?

Comment: @Hayden [`typing.List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) was deprecated in favor using the builtin `list`. See [PEP-585](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/)

Comment: @Hayden `type(lambda x: x ** 2)` is `<class 'function'>`

Comment: a "lambda" isn't a *type*. lambda expressions are a syntactic construct that create *function objects*, they same type of function objects as function definition statements (only they are expression, and can be used anywhere else an expression can be used and statements cannot)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
a: list[Callable] = [lambda x: x ** 2]
```

Comment: this is partially true, but misses the type signature of your functions